# Why isn't PHP's htmlentities() converting the œ character?

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode

I'm having some trouble with PHP's `htmlentities()` / `htmlspecialchars()` functions.  The string I am converting contains the character œ (html equivalent is '&oelig'), yet both `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()` are not converting this character.

When I run `get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES)` to see the translation table that PHP is using, I noticed that the `œ` character is missing, yet other ligaments like `æ` (`&aelig`) are present.  Why is this?  Is there a different way that I'm supposed to convert the œ character?

For reference, I'm running PHP 5.3.14 and here's the output from `get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES)`:

```
array(100) {
  [" "]=>
  string(6) "&nbsp;"
  ["¡"]=>
  string(7) "&iexcl;"
  ["¢"]=>
  string(6) "&cent;"
  ["£"]=>
  string(7) "&pound;"
  ["¤"]=>
  string(8) "&curren;"
  ["¥"]=>
  string(5) "&yen;"
  ["¦"]=>
  string(8) "&brvbar;"
  ["§"]=>
  string(6) "&sect;"
  ["¨"]=>
  string(5) "&uml;"
  ["©"]=>
  string(6) "&copy;"
  ["ª"]=>
  string(6) "&ordf;"
  ["«"]=>
  string(7) "&laquo;"
  ["¬"]=>
  string(5) "&not;"
  ["­"]=>
  string(5) "&shy;"
  ["®"]=>
  string(5) "&reg;"
  ["¯"]=>
  string(6) "&macr;"
  ["°"]=>
  string(5) "&deg;"
  ["±"]=>
  string(8) "&plusmn;"
  ["²"]=>
  string(6) "&sup2;"
  ["³"]=>
  string(6) "&sup3;"
  ["´"]=>
  string(7) "&acute;"
  ["µ"]=>
  string(7) "&micro;"
  ["¶"]=>
  string(6) "&para;"
  ["·"]=>
  string(8) "&middot;"
  ["¸"]=>
  string(7) "&cedil;"
  ["¹"]=>
  string(6) "&sup1;"
  ["º"]=>
  string(6) "&ordm;"
  ["»"]=>
  string(7) "&raquo;"
  ["¼"]=>
  string(8) "&frac14;"
  ["½"]=>
  string(8) "&frac12;"
  ["¾"]=>
  string(8) "&frac34;"
  ["¿"]=>
  string(8) "&iquest;"
  ["À"]=>
  string(8) "&Agrave;"
  ["Á"]=>
  string(8) "&Aacute;"
  ["Â"]=>
  string(7) "&Acirc;"
  ["Ã"]=>
  string(8) "&Atilde;"
  ["Ä"]=>
  string(6) "&Auml;"
  ["Å"]=>
  string(7) "&Aring;"
  ["Æ"]=>
  string(7) "&AElig;"
  ["Ç"]=>
  string(8) "&Ccedil;"
  ["È"]=>
  string(8) "&Egrave;"
  ["É"]=>
  string(8) "&Eacute;"
  ["Ê"]=>
  string(7) "&Ecirc;"
  ["Ë"]=>
  string(6) "&Euml;"
  ["Ì"]=>
  string(8) "&Igrave;"
  ["Í"]=>
  string(8) "&Iacute;"
  ["Î"]=>
  string(7) "&Icirc;"
  ["Ï"]=>
  string(6) "&Iuml;"
  ["Ð"]=>
  string(5) "&ETH;"
  ["Ñ"]=>
  string(8) "&Ntilde;"
  ["Ò"]=>
  string(8) "&Ograve;"
  ["Ó"]=>
  string(8) "&Oacute;"
  ["Ô"]=>
  string(7) "&Ocirc;"
  ["Õ"]=>
  string(8) "&Otilde;"
  ["Ö"]=>
  string(6) "&Ouml;"
  ["×"]=>
  string(7) "&times;"
  ["Ø"]=>
  string(8) "&Oslash;"
  ["Ù"]=>
  string(8) "&Ugrave;"
  ["Ú"]=>
  string(8) "&Uacute;"
  ["Û"]=>
  string(7) "&Ucirc;"
  ["Ü"]=>
  string(6) "&Uuml;"
  ["Ý"]=>
  string(8) "&Yacute;"
  ["Þ"]=>
  string(7) "&THORN;"
  ["ß"]=>
  string(7) "&szlig;"
  ["à"]=>
  string(8) "&agrave;"
  ["á"]=>
  string(8) "&aacute;"
  ["â"]=>
  string(7) "&acirc;"
  ["ã"]=>
  string(8) "&atilde;"
  ["ä"]=>
  string(6) "&auml;"
  ["å"]=>
  string(7) "&aring;"
  ["æ"]=>
  string(7) "&aelig;"
  ["ç"]=>
  string(8) "&ccedil;"
  ["è"]=>
  string(8) "&egrave;"
  ["é"]=>
  string(8) "&eacute;"
  ["ê"]=>
  string(7) "&ecirc;"
  ["ë"]=>
  string(6) "&euml;"
  ["ì"]=>
  string(8) "&igrave;"
  ["í"]=>
  string(8) "&iacute;"
  ["î"]=>
  string(7) "&icirc;"
  ["ï"]=>
  string(6) "&iuml;"
  ["ð"]=>
  string(5) "&eth;"
  ["ñ"]=>
  string(8) "&ntilde;"
  ["ò"]=>
  string(8) "&ograve;"
  ["ó"]=>
  string(8) "&oacute;"
  ["ô"]=>
  string(7) "&ocirc;"
  ["õ"]=>
  string(8) "&otilde;"
  ["ö"]=>
  string(6) "&ouml;"
  ["÷"]=>
  string(8) "&divide;"
  ["ø"]=>
  string(8) "&oslash;"
  ["ù"]=>
  string(8) "&ugrave;"
  ["ú"]=>
  string(8) "&uacute;"
  ["û"]=>
  string(7) "&ucirc;"
  ["ü"]=>
  string(6) "&uuml;"
  ["ý"]=>
  string(8) "&yacute;"
  ["þ"]=>
  string(7) "&thorn;"
  ["ÿ"]=>
  string(6) "&yuml;"
  ["&"]=>
  string(5) "&amp;"
  ["""]=>
  string(6) "&quot;"
  ["<"]=>
  string(4) "&lt;"
  [">"]=>
  string(4) "&gt;"
}
```

Comment: if you output the page as UTF-8, you wouldn't need any of those entities (except `<`, `>` and `&`).

Comment: True, however in my scenario I'm inserting into a database table, not displaying on a web page.  The table isn't UTF-8, so I need this conversion to occur.  I realize I can treat this character as a special case, but I'd rather htmlentities() handle it for me.

Comment: If you use HTML entities in your database, you cannot use the stored data in any other output medium except HTML. Is that really what you want? Make the table utf8, it saves you a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using PHP 5.4.5 and it outputs &oelig correctly. So i cant realy test this, but I guess its because isnt in the actual charset for iso-8859-1 which is used by default. They are in the supplementary character Set. Try using ISO-8859-15

```
htmlentities($s,  ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "ISO-8859-15");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, been fighting for hours with the same issue. The "ISO-8859-15" bit was the key change that helped for me.